# Is this signal classified as DC or AC, and what about the impedance?

Tags: ac, dc, impedance

I have been very confused ever since I started studying electronics, whether this signal is classified as DC or AC. [image]

It is a simple digital electronics simulation. Let's assume that it represents microcontroller communication. I know that for a signal to be AC, it has to alternate, meaning its current should go in both directions in a fluctuating manner, but why do I sometimes see this 0 to +V signal being called AC? All it does is just turn on and off the voltage, not change the direction.

Also, does it make sense to calculate the impedance of this type of signal? If it is DC signal (because current only flows one way), impedance is just active resistance, no reactive components should influence complex impedance. But sometimes I still can find resistance being called impedance in this type of signal circuits. Why is that?

Comment: This is highly opinionated matter - anyway, to me it's "variable direct current" precisely because CURRENT does not change direction. However if you do a FFT and you do analysis in the frequency domain, you have superimposition of DC and AC so that's why this signal would be called AC by some. Regarding impedance, resistance is impedance but impedance can be something beyond resistance (and that's is reactance) - but you calculate impedance of a circuit, not of a signal.

Comment: But in your terms that is AC, since it can both charge and discharge a capacitor, so the current alternates, even if voltage is always non-negative. That's because the derivative of voltage will go both positive and negative. And sure there will be an impedance pushing current and pulling current, and since ideal circuits do not exist, the impedance is non-zero, and since it is a transistor driving the line, it is not a fixed resistance. And the concept of impedance includes resistive and non-resistive parts.

Answer (score 5):

> but why do I sometimes see this 0 to +V signal being called AC?

Depending on the context, you may call it "AC with DC offset", or "DC with AC component" (e.g. ripple).

The DC offset of the signal is the average value which is the signed area under the waveform divided by the time duration. If the signal is periodic then the average of the entire signal is equal to the one period's average. So, if you remove this average value from the signal you'll get the AC, or likewise, if you can remove the AC (with filters) you'll get the average value.

For example, a sinewave has a zero DC value because the area of positive and negative parts cancel each other i.e. total signed area becomes zero. But if you apply a DC offset, these areas will not be equal:

[image]

<sup>[Img Src](https://www.pngitem.com/middle/hJJmiwR_sine-wave-with-dc-offset-hd-png-download/)</sup>

A rectified sinewave can also be considered "DC" with AC component:

[image]

It's a periodic signal, so the average equals to one period's average i.e. the area under the waveform. Without the DC component, it'd look something like this (do not scale):

[image]

> Also, does it make sense to calculate the impedance of this type of signal?

Impedance concept doesn't apply to signals. In other words, signals don't have impedance.

But if you mean if it makes sense to calculate impedance of some components which are under the influence of this type of signal then it's a different story.

We normally define the impedance for sinusoidal inputs i.e. the ratio of complex representation of voltage to the complex representation of current. This is where \$Z_L=j\omega \ L\$ for inductors and \$Z_C=1/j\omega \ C\$ for capacitors come from.

The waveform in your question is not sinusoidal. But Fourier showed us that all signals can be represented as a combination of sinewaves (harmonics), therefore it's theoretically possible to calculate the impedance, but it'll be a big hassle.

For pulse trains having a duty-cycle of 50% (i.e. equal on and off times) a.k.a. square waves we can make an estimation using the first harmonic because most of the energy comes from the first harmonic:

[image]

In the image above, the red is the original pulse, and the black is the first harmonic but with offset, the dashed line (I kept the offset there for better visualisation). The offset (average or DC component) of the square wave is half the amplitude i.e. \$A/2\$. If we remove that offset will get an AC pulse train that swings between \$+A/2\$ and \$-A/2\$. Using this, and the Fourier series, we'll see that the first harmonic (the black sinewave) will have an amplitude of \$2A/\pi\$. Now this can be useful for impedance and related calculations, at least to give some approximated results.

Comment: yeah, I probably meant components that deal with these signals.

Comment: @Dominykas see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is this signal classified as DC or AC*

Sometimes there's a bit of both. You could justifiably call the signal DC because the voltage doesn't appear to go negative but then, if you subtracted the average value of the signal it would be pure AC.

> *Also, does it make sense to calculate the impedance of this type of
> signal?*

Impedances are only meaningful to single sinewave frequencies. Your signal is not a pure sinewave; it comprises many harmonics of the fundamental frequency and, when this happens, impedance doesn't apply.

> *But sometimes I still can find resistance being called impedance in
> this type of signal circuits. Why is that?*

"Resistance" is a subset of "impedance" so, it's not wrong to use either term. "Reactance" is a subset of "impedance" and we don't have problems talking about the impedance of a capacitor or inductor.

Comment: oh, you're back! There's a welcome upvote for you LoL